# I have keys, but I have no locks

Tags: riddle

> I have keys, but I have no locks.
>   Some consider me majestic.
>   Other find me annoying.
>   I can do *bac*k, but not f*orw*a*r*d.
>   I am happy.
>   I am sad.
>   I can hold you in suspense.
>   What am I?

Comment: I thought I had it, but my guess doesn't fit with line 4. Thinking cap on!

Comment: The answer is  "ME". :)

Comment: a bald soprano!

Comment: You seemed to have italicized the wrong letters. Is it intentional?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you :

> A piano?

I have keys, but I have no locks. :

> piano keys

Some consider me majestic

> piano can be majestic

Other find me annoying.

> When badly played it sounds injuring

I can do back but not forward :

> It is wordplay on Johann Sebastian Bach, the composer and pianist. *Forward* is not a composer!

I am happy.

I am sad.

I can hold you in suspense.

> music transfers emotions, and piano is often used in high suspense movie music (e.g., Psycho's score for instance)

2nd Shot for those three lines (thanks to comments from Mark A, and Peter)

> Happy stands for Major Scale, Sad for minor scale, and the suspense bite stands for Suspended scale.

Comment: I'm digging in my brain but it happens that he isn't so deep... Still looking for it, if anyone else got a clue !

Comment: suspense could be because of the sustain pedal

Comment: Are these related to song titles?

Comment: The italic letters in `bac`k are keys, and the italic letters in f`orw`a`r`d are not keys.

Comment: "Happy" - Major scale, "Sad" - Minor scale?

Comment: Retreating is consider as comming back. I remember from my art lessons, there is technique in music which is called Fugue. The word is coming from Latin and means to flee. Is it a reason why you can do back not forward?

Comment: Does the suspense refer to suspended chords/scales?

Comment: @Peter I was about to post that

Comment: Probably a long shot, but since _bac(k)_ was a double hint, could it be that _(f)orw(a)r(d)_ is one too, referencing the Finnish group ORW Rap? Bach is written for pianos (and other instruments), whereas ORW’s style of rap/hip-hop consists almost exclusively of beats and lyrics, which a piano won’t be able to play, of course.

Comment: I've never heard of the word "compositor." Unless this is something from non-American English (which I don't believe it is), it should be "composer."

Comment: What about the lock on the boîte diabolique, which houses the nineteen forbidden notes?

Comment: Surprised [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano#Grand) hasn't (has it?) come up yet for "majestic."

Comment: Sorry, couldn't access to the site for some days, but I still have no idea for the part I got wrong, and it looks like noone really does (except the suspended chords/scales maybe?)  and sorry for grammar mistakes and thanks for the edit. Still looking forward those 3 lines

Comment: Well, I added it in my answer then, so everyone can see it

Answer (score 10):

A long shot, but here goes

> A memory

I have keys, but I have no locks.

> Memories are they keys to not repeating the same mistakes

Some consider me majestic.

> You can have a good memory

Other find me annoying.

> It may be a curse to remember everything

I can go back, but not forward.

> You cannot have memories from the future.

I am happy.

> I remember when my son was born

I am sad.

> I remember when my father died.

I can hold you in suspense.

> But I cannot remember the name of that actor in that movie with that thing in that city that ended with that....how the hell did it end?

Comment: Interesting, but no.

Answer (score 9):

Are you

> A typewriter?

I have keys, but I have no locks.

> All typewriters have keys, but the earliest didn't have any caps lock or shift lock as they called it back then.

Some consider me majestic.

> Some people romanticize typewriters to be a majestic relic of the past

Other find me annoying.

> Many people wouldn't want to type on a typewriter in an era with backspace and spellcheck

I can do back, but not forward.

> Later models of typewriters incorporated very simple backspace functionality, but they lacked full navigation through the text

I am happy.

> :)

I am sad.

> :(

I can hold you in suspense.

> Many suspense novels have been typed out on a typewriter

What am I?

> You're a typewriter!

Answer (score 3):

This one is the most outrageous answer yet.

Are you...

> a CS:GO case?

I have keys but I have no locks...

> CS:GO cases have keys that you can buy but no locks.

Some consider me majestic...

> Many new players will celebrate with joy when they see a CS:GO case.

Others find me annoying...

> Some people get annoyed when they don't get the CS:GO case.

I can do back but not forward...

> The cases scroll backwards, but not forward.

I am happy...
I am sad...
I can hold you in suspense...

> A CS:GO case can inflict all of these emotions to the person opening it. Sometimes you get an amazing item, sometimes you get rubbish in the case, but until you open it, you are in suspense of what's inside.

Answer (score 1):

I want to put forward the answer

> God

I have keys, but I have no locks.

> God's ways could be considered the keys to entering heaven or being a better person

Some consider me majestic.

> Some think the concept of God is majestic

Other find me annoying.

> Some people are annoyed by belief in God

I can do back, but not forward.

> Many actions by God seem to be stories based in the past

I am happy. I am sad.

> God has many moods and acts accordingly to them

I can hold you in suspense.

> Some people wait for a sign from God or for prayers to be answered.

What am I?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is the correct solution but it fits most of the points.

You are

> A movie

I have keys, but I have no locks.

> Movies or videos consist of keyframes. I don't think there are any locks.

Some consider me majestic.

> There are many movies and some can really be called majestic.

Other find me annoying.

> Bad movies or movies with bad voice acting can be really annoying.

I can do back, but not forward.
(I'm a bit stuck on this one)

> When a movie shows on TV, you can rewind it but not play it forward (you can if you have it on dvd or downloaded though).
>  Alteratively, you can see the movies that came before it but can't see the next one before it is created.

I am happy.

> There are many happy movies! :)

I am sad.

> There are many sad movies. :(

I can hold you in suspense.

> Yes, movies can definitely hold someone in suspense!
>  Even when waiting for the next one in the series to come out!

Comment: The correct solution was already found, but nice try! Welcome to Puzzling!